# Hiding a GridView ID column

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Seems to be a common issue.

I'm trying to hide a column of my GridView. I have read that simply setting the column to 'visible = false' will not work as I'm auto-generating my data.

Currently my code stands as so:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bind();

        if (GridView1.Columns.Count > 0)
            GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        else
        {
            GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Visible = false;
            foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                gvr.Cells[1].Visible = false;
            }
        }

    }
```

The 'if' statement will not trigger as as said I am auto-generating the data. With the above loop, I can hide the header text of the column but want to hide the whole column with the ability to still be able to access the hidden data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about just doing this later in the control's life cycle (when the Columns collection has been populated):

```
protected void GridView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (GridView1.Columns.Count > 0)
        GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
    else
    {
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Visible = false;
        foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            gvr.Cells[1].Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: you would need to add `OnPreRender="GridView1_PreRender"` to your GridView markup.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have seen this method but Im not sure what I should be supplying to the method in the form of the object and eventArgs? Also will that 'else' not just hide the cell headerif it is triggered? As I dont want that to happen, just for the entire column to be hidden

Comment: @user1352057 You don't need to supply anything. If you add the markup I mentioned at the end, the event will "hook up" automatically. Re: the `else` thing, I just copied your code in. If you don't want the else to hide the header, by all means leave that out.

Comment: again thanks for your help. When you say about the onprerender. do i need to declare this within my onload? I have tried adding it but currently am getting an error.

Comment: @user1352057 What's the error you're getting?  You should just be able to add that text to your GridView markup (in the .aspx page).

Comment: I have added my code to the original question. I have declared it within the aspx page but im still receiving an error that my columns are 0.

Comment: As shown i believe I have added the prerender to the correct part of my declared gridview

Comment: @user1352057 That's *really* odd.  Yeah, you're code looks okay.  I've got to run for a while, but I will try and take a look later tonight.

Comment: @jardarnel27 Managed to sort it in the end through an RowDataBound method.

Comment: @user1352057 I'm glad you were able to get it worked out, and that I was able to help out in some capacity =)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the `GridView.DataKeyNames` and `GridView.DataKeys` properties to store the ID and then retrieve it with the rowIndex later? This also will keep the column from being autogenerated.

[DataKeyNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames.aspx)

[DataKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeys.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Ah... so the problem is the Columns is not predefined.

Perhaps you could use Linq to select all the columns you want to display:

```
gvTest.DataSource = (from d in dataSource
                     select new 
                     {
                         ColumnA = d.ColumnA...
                     }
```

Alternatively, you could hide the columns with JavaScript;

Comment: I imagine that's already happening behind the scenes in the call to `bind();` in the first line of the OPs Page_Load method.

Comment: @Narnian. Yes bind() calls a method that populates the gridview.#

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation with auto-generating columns.  You give up a lot of control over HOW the columns are displayed for the convenience of not pre-defining them.

Bite the bullet now and define your columns. If this is the ONLY customization you need to make, you may be all right, but 90+% of the time I end up defining columns to customize how they are displayed.

Otherwise you're going to end up with several of these "tweaks" that are prone to breaking under various circumstances (e.g. the order of the columns changes in the data source).

Comment: @D Stanley Thanks for your answer. Do you mean predefine them server side?

Comment: No, you can define them in the markup.  The designer should give you screens to add columns at design-time.